# Overlapping div on top of iframe

Tags: html, css, css-float

The overlapping div with a class:

```
.eStore-product {
  height:180px;
  padding:5px;
  clear:both;
}
```

I thought by adding `clear:both;` that this could solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your iframe should not be placed within a p tag; iframes should go by themselves.  Secondly, your `.eStore-product` has a height of 180px which is causing the problem.  Either increasing that height or adding a `margin-bottom: 100px;` would solve the problem.

Unfortunately this solution is more a hack than anything.  [I feel you've got a bigger problem than just this one line](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://performancecarclub.org/portfolio/beaver-run-bachelor-gulch-715-716/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Try fixing the 8 errors you have on the page and you mind find yourself having to fix less of these bizarre problems.

Comment: Thanks.  I found an iframe plugin for WP that fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm strange behavior, I would try 
Enclose the map frame in a div, and apply a padding top:

```
<div style="padding-top:110px">
```

this at line 226 and div clousure with the current closing divs at 228

```
</div></div></div>
```

it gives enough space. The current div scope seems right. I did a quick check on divs and seems right, but maybe a deeper revision could bring the problem with the clear.

Answer (score 0):

I try to put margin inside the p tag, and the result is not overlapping
I hope it is useful for you

Comment: Confused?  Can you explain further?  Thanks!

Comment: I study your coding
it stated 

<p>
<iframe></iframe>
</p>

I try to put <p style="margin-top:100px">
and the result is not overlapping

Comment: Thanks for your time, but your answer isn't quite right.  Possibly I'm missing something.